# Firebase Cloud Functions fail with no logs, just "Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason"

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I infrequently see this error in my Firebase Cloud Functions logs:

"Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging Request rejected.".

I looked through the logs around the time this error occurred and don't see any other information, just a few other successful executions of the same cloud function. The same function is executing successfully thousands of times a day, but then once every day or few hours this is shown. My entire cloud function body is wrapped in a try/catch and I've seen logical errors reported properly from the error log in the catch code so I don't know how this uncaught error is happening or how to get any more information about it. Does anyone know how this error could be happening? This is a sanitized version of the function throwing this weird error:

```
exports.onUserDocUpdate = functions.firestore
  .document('user/{userId}/{collectionId}/{docId}')
  .onWrite(handleDocumentWrite);
  
async function handleDocumentWrite(change, context) {
  try {
    // Function logic here
  } catch (error) {
    functions.logger.error(`firestoreTriggers.handleDocumentWrite failed with error:`, error);
  }
}
```

Comment: I was looking for anything similar but nothing found at all. I think the best action you may want to take is to create an [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187195&template=0). Just remember to mark it as private if you share your projectID

Comment: Thanks YeriPelona. I opened a troubleshooting issue against firebase yesterday and will update this question when firebase gets back to me.

Comment: Cool, I'll looking into this since this got my curiosity

Comment: @AlexEgli What happened to the issue you opened? I have also started seeing this error on Firebase Functions.

Comment: @harsh989 They replied to me about the issue in early June 2021 and said:
"The issue here has been identified to be rooted in some other internal changes that should be resolved in an undetermined near future. I wish I had an estimate, sorry.
 
All I can say so far is that it’s a problem that our product engineers are aware of and working on already :).
There’s no estimated resolution time for now."

For other reasons I was unable to use Firebase so I haven't actually been following or checking this issue anymore.